# Recuperar objeto json

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
{
  codigo : "1",
  nome   : "Carlos"
}
```

Classe java (POJO)

```
public class usuario{
   @SerializedName("codigo")
   private int codigo;

   @SerializedName("nome")
   private String nome;

   /* ... */
}
```

A chamada

```
Call<Usuario> getUsuario(@Query("codigo")
```

Como é que eu chamo esse objeto usando retrofit?

Estou tentando assim:

```
private void getUsuario ( Service service, int codigo ){
        Call<Usuario> userCall = service.getUsuario( codigo );
        userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response) {
                Log.i("User body",response.toString());
                if( response.isSuccessful() ){

                   //Não sei o que fazer 

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("onFailure Usuario", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Pra obter o resultado é response.body faz assim: Usuario respostaservice = response.body dai tu instancia a classe usuário (o POJO que tu criou ) e salva assim: usuario.setnome = respostaservice.getnome, se for de uma lista é um pouco diferente, isso tudo dentro do response

Comment: Realmente, minhas listas funcionaram direitinho

Comment: Do seu jeito funcionou!

Comment: Pode adicionar como resposta, por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra obter o resultado é response.body faz assim: Usuario respostaservice = response.body dai tu instancia a classe usuário (o POJO que tu criou ) e salva assim: usuario.setnome = respostaservice.getnome, se for de uma lista é um pouco diferente, isso tudo dentro do response

Answer (score 1):

O `Body` do seu `response`já é seu objeto!

Então, tente da seguinte forma:

```
private void getUsuario ( Service service, int codigo ){
        Call<Usuario> userCall = service.getUsuario( codigo );
        userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response) {
                Log.i("User body",response.toString());
                if( response.isSuccessful() ){

                   //VAMOS PEGAR O USUARIO
                   Usuario usuario = response.body();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("onFailure Usuario", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```